# UWP: Zoom In/Out in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, scrollviewer, uwp-xaml

I am having problem with zoom-in and zoom-out in GridView. Actually, zooming works fine, however, I am not able to pan to the right. When I tried to pan to the right, it always snap it back to the left (panning top and bottom works ok).

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled">
    <GridView x:Name="gvItems">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#cfcfcf">
                    <StackPanel Width="128" MaxWidth="128">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImgPath}" Width="128" Height="128" Stretch="UniformToFill"></Image>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" BorderBrush="#cfcfcf" Padding="5 0 5 0" Height="32">
                            <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

You need to add **VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"** and **HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"** in ScrollViewer then set its content to bind to ScrollViewer's **ViewportWidth** and **ViewportHeight**

Here is the code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="svList" MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <GridView x:Name="gvItems" Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, ElementName=svList}" Height="{Binding Path=ViewportHeight, ElementName=svList}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#cfcfcf">
                    <StackPanel Width="128" MaxWidth="128">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImgPath}" Width="128" Height="128" Stretch="UniformToFill"></Image>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" BorderBrush="#cfcfcf" Padding="5 0 5 0" Height="32">
                            <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I hope this post could help someone who found themselves in similar situation.

Cheers,
Sam